# How to download a log file with Ant until a specific string is found?

Tags: ant, wait, repeat

I'm trying to delay the execution of an Ant task until a remote log (which I should download every time) contains a specific string.

The operation should happen like this:

1. Download the log file from the server
2. Use regex to figure out if the string is there
3. If the string is not there, repeat from step 1 (or until a timeout is reached)

I don't know how to implement the "repeat" part.

I found that the waitfor task might help here, but it accepts only conditions so I cannot add the first 2 steps as children.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

ANT is a build tool, not a continuous integration engine.

For an example of the latter try setting up Jenkins to run your ANT build, using a build trigger plugin. Th [URLTrigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URLTrigger+Plugin) can be configured to look for a particular text string.